# How do I bypass Chrome's Autoplay policy the same way as Youtube does?

Tags: google-chrome, frontend, autoplay

I need to make a video **autoplay with sound** when visited via a **deeplink**.

According to https://developer.chrome.com/blog/autoplay/, it is not allowed, because the video is NOT muted.

However, if you open a Youtube video in a **Guest** Chrome tab (meaning [Media Engagement Index](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/autoplay/#media-engagement-index) is empty and doesn't matter here), it autoplays, and it has sound.

That means Youtube bypasses the Chrome policy, is that correct? I saw other websites do the same as well.

I am wondering how to do the same in my app. Could anyone teach me?

Note: the video in my app is from a 3rd party and is embedded in my app, that means the video's URL has a different domain from my app's. But I think it shouldn't matter.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can't bypass it unless you have connections in Google and get on the list, here is blog post where they admit that there is a whitelist of pages https://blog.google/products/chrome/improving-autoplay-chrome/, which is imho very unfair and discriminates competition. For those non-listed here are rules: https://developer.chrome.com/blog/autoplay/